# Making a calender in PHP but can't get it into a grid

Tags: php, html, css, calendar

So I am making a calender form for a client to choose a course to book... this then uploads to a link table between the course and the customer but I cant for the life of me get the calender into a calender like grid properly... my code is simple and sweet but i need to do this non object orientated (i have small java experience but nothing else)....

I have ben staring at this all day but to no avail!

(I am learning so im not going down the routes of protecting it etc... this is for self learning so just needs to work and help me understand where I am going wrong)

The code:

```
<?
if(@$_POST['month'])
{    
$_SESSION['month'] = trim($_POST['month']);
}

elseif(!isset($_SESSION['month']))
{    
$_SESSION['month'] = '3';
}

if(@$_POST['year'])
{    
$_SESSION['year'] = trim($_POST['year']);
}

elseif(!isset($_SESSION['year']))
{    
$_SESSION['year'] = '2012';
}

?>

<form name="sort" action="calender.php" method="post">
<select name="month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>    
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select name="year">
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value=" - !Go! - " />
</form><br />
<?php



$month = $_SESSION['month'];
$year = $_SESSION['year'];
$day = 1;

$nummonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

echo "<form name='choosedate' action='datechosen' method='get'>";

for($day = 1; $day <= $nummonth; $day++)
{

echo $day."/".$month."/".$year."<input type='radio' name='coursedate value='".$day."-".$month."-".$year."' /><br />";

}

echo "<input type='submit' value=' - Submit - ' /></form>";

?>
```

Thank you for any help you can give... any advice or even just a point in the right direction is much much much appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "grid"?  What I see with your code is two separate HTML forms.  One has a drop-down of months and dates and another tries to output the date into a radio button?  It's not making a lot of sense to me.  Also consider the jQuery UI datepicker.  That might help: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: the drop down menus display let you choose what month or year you wish to see... there is html in there (echoed php) that displays all the dates in the month that you have selected for that year. when I say grid... my calender just displays all dates in text but a grid as in a table calender you may have on your desk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function I threw together that should work with your current code. To use the function, simply call it by this:

```
# $month, $year must be numeric.  ie. Aug = 8
# The 3rd parameter is optional.  It will display the calendar month starting 
# on either Monday or Sunday, depending on your preference.  Default is 'sun',
# but anything other than 'sun' will cause the displayed week to start on Monday.

printCalendarMonth($month, $year, 'mon');
```

Then you need to include the code below.  I've commented in it to help.

```
function printCalendarMonth($month, $year, $firstDay = 'sun')
{
    # Get the number of days in the month
    $totalDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    # Get the day-of-the-week the 1st starts on
    $date = getDayOfTheWeek($month,$year, $firstDay);
    # print out the table headers
    printTableHeader($date, $firstDay);
    # print table body
    printTableBody($totalDays, $date['startDay']);
    # print out the table headers
    printTableFooter();

}

function printTableHeader($date, $firstDay)
{
    # The standard "Sunday First" calendar of days
    $days = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'); 
    # change to the "Monday First" calendar
    if($firstDay == 'mon'){
        # the days of the week
        $days = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'); 
    }
    # print the header HTML for the calendar table
    echo '<h1>' . $date['month'] . ', ' . $date['year'] . '</h1>' . "\n";
    echo '<table>' . "\n";
    echo "\t" . '<thead>' . "\n";
    echo "\t\t" . '<tr>' . "\n";
    # loop through the days and print them out
    foreach($days as $day){
        echo "\t\t\t" . '<th>' . $day . '</th>' . "\n"; 
    }
    # close table header HTML
    echo "\t\t" . '</tr>' . "\n";
    echo "\t" . '</thead>' . "\n";
    echo "\t" . '<tbody>' . "\n";
}

function printTableBody($totalDays, $startDay)
{
    # value to represent the day the last day of the month falls on
    $endDay = 6;
    # value to represent the current day of the week
    $currDay = 1;
    # Loop through all the days of the month
    for($todayDate=1; $todayDate <= $totalDays; $todayDate++){
        # start a new row every 7 days
        if($currDay % 7 == 1) { echo "\t\t" . '<tr>' . "\n"; }
        # increment the current day (do this before the closing table row)
        $currDay++;
        # loop through the number of starting days to represent the days of the previous month
        $currDay = printPrevMonthDays($startDay, $currDay);
        # print out the table cell for this day.  Start a new row for every 7 days
        echo "\t\t\t" . '<td>'.$todayDate.'</td>' . "\n";
        # close the table row every 7 days
        if($currDay % 7 == 1) { echo "\t\t" . '</tr>' . "\n"; }
    }
}

function printTableFooter($firstDay)
{
    echo "\t" . '</tbody>' . "\n";
    echo '</table>' . "\n";
}

function getDayOfTheWeek($month, $year, $firstDay = 'sun')
{
    $date = array();
    # save out the date values
    $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    $date['dotw'] = strtolower( date("D", $time) );
    $date['month'] = strtolower( date("F", $time) );
    $date['year'] = strtolower( date("Y", $time) );

    switch($date['dotw']){
        default:
        case 'sun': $date['startDay'] = 0; break;
        case 'mon': $date['startDay'] = 1; break;
        case 'tue': $date['startDay'] = 2; break;
        case 'wed': $date['startDay'] = 3; break;
        case 'thu': $date['startDay'] = 4; break;
        case 'fri': $date['startDay'] = 5; break;
        case 'sat': $date['startDay'] = 6; break;
    }
    # subtract one if we want to display Monday as the first day of the week
    if($firstDay == 'mon')
        $date['startDay'] = $date['startDay'] - 1;
    # return date array object
    return $date;
}

# passing startDay by reference
function printPrevMonthDays(&$startDay, $currDay)
{
    while($startDay != 0){
        echo "\t\t\t" . '<td>[blank]</td>' . "\n";  
        # increment the current day
        $currDay++;
        # decrement the startDay
        $startDay--;    
    }
    # return zero to 
    return $currDay;
}
```

The main concept is as DaveyBoy states, it's just a X-by-X array.  The only real trick is that days don't always start on the first day of the week, so you need to print out some "blank" days of the previous month.

You could easily do this by creating a 7-by-X 2D array and just loop through that, but it will be the same concepts where you need to fill in the blank spaces.

Of course, there's some hard coded values in there, which can be improved upon but for the sake of this tutorial, here it is.

Hope it helps!
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I used your code and had a real play around with the concept and we are up and running... thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this myself but it took quite a bit of doing. Nowadays, I use jQuery-ui.

There is a date picker built into it and it's pretty configurable. It can do individual dates or ranges. I've used it before and it was pretty simple to get going (even with my limited javaScript experience)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

I *think* that this is the code I describe in one of my comments below. Sorry if it's convoluted - it's from my early days as a PHP coder.

```
<?php
/**
 *  Calendar functions
 */

    function ConvDate(&$D)
    {
        $TempDate=substr($D,8,2)."/".substr($D,5,2)."/".substr($D,0,4);
        $D=$TempDate;
    }

/**
 *  Function to display a calendar of a month
 */

    function DispCalendar($Month=NULL,$Year=NULL, $Link=NULL, $VarName=NULL,$highlight=NULL)
    {
        $DIM=array('01'=>31,'02'=>28,'03'=>31,'04'=>30,'05'=>31,'06'=>30,'07'=>31,'08'=>31,'09'=>30,'10'=>31,'11'=>30,'12'=>31);

/**
 *  Set default values for Month and Year if none supplied
 */
        if (empty($Month))
        {
            $Month=date("m");
        }
        if (empty($Year))
        {
            $Year=date("Y");
        }

/**
 *  Add a leading zero to the month number if required
 */
        $Month=str_pad($Month,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);

/**
 *  Check for a leap year. The rule is that the year is divisible by 4 or 400 (eg 2000). Year values with an odd number of centuries (eg 1900)
 *  are NOT leap years. Easiest way to deal with this is all years where there is a remainder when dividing by 100 and none when
 *  dividing by 4 or when there is no remainder when dividing by 400
 *  Use the "Exact equivalence" operator (===) as 0 is used as a value for "false"
 */
        if ((((($Year % 4)===0) && (($Year % 100)!==0)) || ($Year % 400)===0) && ($Month==2))
        {
            $DaysInMonth=29;
        } else
        {
            $DaysInMonth=$DIM[$Month];
        }

/**
 *  If a link has been passed and no variable name or vice versa, clear them as it's pointless having one without the other
 */
        if ((isset($Link) && !isset($VarName)) || (!isset($Link) && isset($VarName)))
        {
            unset ($Link);
            unset ($VarName);
        }

/**
 *  First day of the selected month
 */
        $FOMTS=mktime(0,0,0,$Month,1,$Year);

/**
 *  Today's date
 */
        $todayDay=date("d");
        $todayMonth=date("m");
        $todayYear=date("Y");

/**
 *  Which day of the week does the first fall on. Sunday=0
 */
        $FirstFallsOn=date("w",$FOMTS);
/**
 *  Full month name
 */
        $LongMonth=date("F",$FOMTS);
        $LongYear=$Year;
/**
 *  Start a table
 */
        echo "<table width=\"100%\" class=\"cal\">\n";
/**
 *  Display the month and the year
 */
            echo "\t<tr>\n";
            echo "\t\t<th colspan=7>$LongMonth - $LongYear</th>\n";
            echo "\t</tr>\n";

/**
 *  Display the days of the week
 */         echo "\t<tr>\n";
            foreach (array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat") as $day)
            {
                echo "\t\t<td width=\"14.28%\">$day</td>\n";
            }
            echo "\t</tr>\n";

/**
 *  Pad out the table cells until the correct day of the week has been reached for the first of the month. Keep
 *  track of the number of cells
 */
            echo "\t<tr>\n";
            for ($dayCounter=0; $dayCounter<$FirstFallsOn; $dayCounter++)
            {
                echo "\t\t<td></td>\n";
            }
/**
 *  Start a counter to keep track of the number of days displayed
 */
            $dayOfMonth=1;

/**
 *  Display the days of the month
 */
            for ($dayOfMonth=1; $dayOfMonth<=$DaysInMonth; $dayOfMonth++)
            {
/**
 *  If the date being displayed is today's date, highlight it in a colour
 */
                $class=((($dayOfMonth==$todayDay) && ($Year==$todayYear) && ($Month==$todayMonth)) ? " class=\"today\"" : ($highlight==($dayOfMonth.$Month.$Year) ? " class=\"calChosen\"" : NULL));


                echo "\t\t<td$class>";
                if (isset($Link))
                {
                    $FL="$Link?$VarName=";
                    $FL.=str_pad($dayOfMonth,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).$Month.$Year;
                    echo "<a href=\"$FL\">$dayOfMonth</a>";
                } else
                {
                    echo $dayOfMonth;
                }
                echo "</td>\n";
                $dayCounter++;
                if (($dayCounter % 7)===0)
                {
                    echo "\t</tr>\n\t<tr>\n";
                }
            }

            for (;($dayCounter%7)!==0; $dayCounter++)
            {
                echo "\t\t<td></td>\n";
            }
            echo "\t</tr>\n";
        echo "</table>\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yet another amazement of jquery... it never ceases to amaze me... it is horribly addictive. My problem is that I want a third person to be able to set up dates in the database that are available, then I want customers to be able to choose those dates... so admin says 25th dec 2012 = 5 slots available, so then 5 customers can choose the same date... might be difficult...

Comment: so using this system I have got the db allocating date to number of slots, then an ifelse statement to allow that date to be subitted that many times, but now want it in a grid! for the purposes of what I am learning this method will do but want it to look nice and pretty!

Comment: I guess that there's two ways to do it: 1 - have a separate entry for each slot per day (so, with your example, 5 entries for 25th dec), or 2 - an entry in the DB with the count of available slots per day. Once a date is picked form the user form, a quick bit of AJAX could say that whether a slot is available on that date? Not speaking from experience here but I could see it being feasible

Comment: If you're determined to go via your route, follow a method like this: 1 - assign each column in a 7-column table a number corresponding to the day number (e.g., Sunday=1, Monday=1 etc). 2 - Calculate the day-number of the 1st of the month (this gives you the number of blank cells in a row). 3 - loop through the number of days in the month and each time you reach day 7 (e.g., Saturday), close the row and start a new one). 4 - once you reach the end of the month, fill in the blank cells until you reach day 7 again. I know it sounds compliated but draw it out on paper and it's reasonably clear

Comment: Just added code I used to use to my original answer. Hope it helps